# Works when hot reload but not when reinstalled

Tags: flutter, dart

I've tried load image which is in the application directory.It's not loading when I reinstalled the app.But it's works fine when after restarting using IDE.What would be the reason for this?

Code is following code

```
 _decideImageView(){
  if(File('$_localPath/name.jpg').existsSync() == false){
    return AssetImage("assets/example.jpeg");
  }else{
    return AssetImage('$_localPath/name.jpg');
  }
```

Comment: 1) Is that issue in iPhone simulator ? 2) What is the value of `_localPath` ? and how you are getting that value ?

Comment: you set the assets directory inside the file `pubspec.yaml `?

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo Assets Image works fine.I have problem with Image in Application Document Directory which is wrote to disk by Image Picker.

Comment: @MidhunMP It's loaded by initState and that contain the path of Application Document Directory..And I'm using Android phone via usb debugging

Answer (score 0):

Using FileImage instead of Assetimage will solve the problem

```
return FileImage(File('$_localPath/name.jpg'));
```